# updating the online counter without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, counter

Help me please. I have a script on my site that shows (online player counter on the server in GTA), when the page loads, it starts from zero to the number of players on the site. [counter code][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gkkX.jpg

```
var updateInterval = 700;
_timer = setInterval(updatePlayerCount, updateInterval);

function ShowCounter() {
  clearInterval(_timer);
  $('#online').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
}

function updatePlayerCount() {
  var ip = "rage2.grand-rp.su:22005";
  $.getJSON('https://cdn.rage.mp/master', function(masterlist) {
    if(masterlist[ip] != undefined){
      document.getElementById('online').innerHTML = masterlist[ip].players;
      ShowCounter();
    }
  });
}
```

I have a _timer, it should update the numbers without reloading the page, but somehow it doesn't work. How to fix it? I posted this on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kg8uap9d/8/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setInteval, use setTimeout

```
var updateInterval = 5000;
_timer = setTimeout(updatePlayerCount, updateInterval);


function updatePlayerCount() {
  var ip = "rage2.grand-rp.su:22005";
  $.getJSON('https://cdn.rage.mp/master', function(masterlist) {
    if(masterlist[ip] != undefined){
      document.getElementById('online').innerHTML = masterlist[ip].players;
      ShowCounter();
      _timer = setTimeout(updatePlayerCount, updateInterval);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i need to call a function regularly using setinterval